# No wild favorite tags seen on mobile Safari, tourists demand refund

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-watching, mobile-web

If you have wildcards in your favorite (or ignored) tags on the site, the mobile view will not correctly highlight questions that match these wildcards. For instance, I have `mass-effect*` as a favorite tag on Gaming:

[image: side-by-side comparison of highlighting in mobile and normal views]

This is because the mobile version of `applyPrefs` just does a direct equals comparison of the texts, so the `*` is interpreted literally and thus nothing ever matches.

Comment: "the last one didn't read right so you get this instead" Well, I feel cheated - I demand a refund!

Comment: +1 just for the fantastic "headline". More posts should follow suit.

Comment: +1 just because you have mass-effect favorited.

Comment: :O you can have wild cards in favs/ignores? There's one feature I didn't know about.

Comment: @Jeroen Yep. You just have to be careful when adding them, since if you accidentally make a selection from the autocomplete it'll remove the `*`

Comment: Well, I alfeady f****** love it! Gonna search meta see if there's more of these hidden gems! +1 on the Q too, nobody should be cheated out of this feature, not even Safari users!

Comment: +1 I didn't know about this wild card feature either, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will start working after the next build.  The rules should be the same as the full site, e.g. if you're visiting `/questions/tagged/feature-request` then the `[feature-*]` wildcard **will not** apply (since *everything* would be highlighted, or grayed out, or hidden).  Everywhere else they should work, highlighting your favorites and graying/hiding your ignored.

Please keep in mind if you have a *lot* of wildcards and an under-powered mobile device you may see a performance impact...but I think you'd have max out both ends of that spectrum to see a noticeable difference.

Comment: Sound good!  Thanks :)