# Favorite tags with wildcards are not highlighted in mobile view

Tags: bug, tag-watching, mobile-web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No wild favorite tags seen on mobile Safari, tourists demand refund](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125316/no-wild-favorite-tags-seen-on-mobile-safari-tourists-demand-refund)

I have several favorite tags that include wild cards, for example:

- `osx*`
- `mac*`

These are highlighted on the normal "full" site, but not on the mobile version.

Note: I'm using the latest iOS, but I guess this isn't related.