# Wildcard favorite tags not highlighting on mobile version of the site

Tags: bug, tag-watching, mobile-web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No wild favorite tags seen on mobile Safari, tourists demand refund](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125316/no-wild-favorite-tags-seen-on-mobile-safari-tourists-demand-refund)

I'm not a fancy schmancy power mobile user, so I don't know how to provide screenshots.

Essentially, I am making use of a feature on the full site where you can put wildcards into your favorite tags. For example, I have "diablo*" favorited instead of [diablo](/questions/tagged/diablo), [diablo-2](/questions/tagged/diablo-2), [diablo-3](/questions/tagged/diablo-3), [diablo-3-monk](/questions/tagged/diablo-3-monk), etc. On the mobile site, no Diablo content is highlighted at all.

For League of Legends, I am using [league-of-legends](/questions/tagged/league-of-legends) without any wildcards, and that one works fine on the mobile site.

Comment: In case it's relevant, I'm using a DROID3 on Android version 2.3.4